# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: key

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pysqlite

I have a error, it's `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: key`, but i don't know whats the problem. I tried changing the `.db` file name from `apiKeys.db` to `key.db` but still raises the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: key`. The code is

```
class Auth:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("key.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS key (
                key)""")
    def add(key):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("key.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO key VALUES (key=:key)",
                {'key': key})
        return True
    def get_all():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("key.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM key")
        return c.fetchall()
    def check(key):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("key.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM key")
        keys = c.fetchall()
        if key in keys:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def remove(key):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("key.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        with conn:
            c.execute("DELETE FROM key WHERE (key=:key)",
                {"key": key})
        return True
```

i added

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("key.db")
c = conn.cursor()
```

to the start of every function because without it, it would always raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `INSERT INTO key VALUES (key=:key)` is not correct [execute syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). Only the placholder should be in the VALUES clause, ie `VALUES (:key)`. (The `remove` method has similar problem).